# Plink > didn't return newline carriage

Tags: linux, windows, bash, putty, plink

this supposed to be very basic.
I'm running plink from windows and want to get some output to a file
plink 192.168.229.128 -ssh -l root -pw password runsql.sh > result.log

the runsql.sh output is something like

```
121211212
213212312
434234234
521312312
```

however the result.log shows as:

```
121211212213212312434234234521312312
```

How can I fix this? thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you open the unix line ending file in `notepad.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have opened unix line ending file in `notepad.exe` or some low-end editor, that does not understand line endings.

If you are always going to check the result in this manner, you can try adding this at the start of your script:

```
[ "$SSH_CONNECTION" -a  ! -t 1 ] && exec 1> >(sed 's/$/\r/')
```

Note that there should be a better & more robust mechanism to do detect that the output is being redirected over ssh session.